# Topological Sorting of a directed acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-algorithm, topological-sort

How would you output all the possible topological sorts for a directed acyclic graph? For example, given a graph where V points to W and X, W points to Y and Z, and X points to Z:

```
V --> W --> Y
      W --> Z
V --> X --> Z
```

How do you topologically sort this graph to produce all possible results? I was able to use a breadth-first-search to get V, W, X, Y, Z and a depth-first search to get V, W, Y, Z, X. But wasn't able to output any other sorts.

Comment: Do a normal topological sort. Each iteration grab all the items you can output, and output them in all their combinations, then move on to the next iteration.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That's a start, but it's more complicated than that.  Suppose that in the first iteration there are 2 vertices A and B with no in-edges.  Both A and B have an edge to C, but only A has an edge to D.  Neither C nor D has any out-edges.  Then A, D, B, C is a valid topological sort, even though D appears before B, and could not be generated by your approach.

Comment: Please check the answer I posted instead, my above comment was too simple, I realised that and also realised I could not post a good enough answer through a comment anyway.

Comment: In short, my comment should be more like: Do a normal topological sort. Each iteration grab all the items you can output and put them in a list, then put that list in a list (list of iteration-lists). Then when done all the iterations of the normal topological sort, do all permutations of those lists. But this is harder to understand and I can't do it justice in a comment, hence my answer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You're right, my algorithm, even the one I wrote up more complete in my answer, would not work with that example and I don't know how/whether it can be fixed. As I posted in a comment to my answer below, my algorithm is concerned with finding *a* working sort order, and cannot (easily) be coerced to find *all* the sort permutations. Unsure if my answer can be salvaged. I'll leave it up for a while but it clearly does not work with all examples and thus I'm not even sure it found all the correct permutations of the example in the question itself.

Comment: An obvious naive (and horribly bad performing) algorithm would be a full permutations algorithm and do a check if it satisfies the criteria. Perhaps dynamic programming could make this a viable solution. Going to ponder it. A recursive algorithm would probably work as well.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I haven't finished reading through your algorithm yet, but kudos to you for noticing a problem.  (I did notice that the step "Output all elements of the list" seems to necessitate picking some arbitrary order.)  I have a feeling that the only real way to do it is with "brute force" -- try adding each addable element in turn, and then recurse to generate all complete solutions stemming from that choice.

Comment: In my implementations, at that step, I usually have a fall-back sort algorithm to sort those elements so that I get a "stable" sort, ie. each time I throw the same elements with the same arrows at the topological sort code I will get the same output, even if the elements are in some way grouped and each group may be equivalent as far as my algorithm goes. In other words, this is more so that the outside code won't get "random" output each time, as any arbitrary ordering between these isolated elements will still yield a valid topologically sorted collection.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Just curious but what kind of time complexity would a brute force algorithm have?

Comment: @user3802002: I think it can be made to be proportional to the number of valid topological orderings multiplied by the size of each ordering (which is n), which is actually optimal :)  But possibly a log factor or two may be needed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I invite you to have a look at my recursive approach.  When the question is "What is the minimum/maximum/total number of <foo> satisfying <bar>" then DP can be useful, but when you actually need to generate all of them, I don't think it can improve the time or space complexity.

Comment: OK, I have hacked together a C# solution that seems to work, but I think this is just an implementation of what @j_random_hacker has posted. I'll post it as another answer.

Comment: Nope, that solution didn't work either, a simple `A -> B -> C` tripped it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to *count* the number of orderings faster, but the only way to actually *generate* all orderings that I can think of is with a full brute-force recursion.  (I say "brute force", but this is still much better than the brutest-possible brute force approach of testing every possible permutation :) )

Basically, at every step there is a set S of vertices remaining (i.e. which have not been added to the order yet), and a subset X of these can be safely added in the next step.  This subset X is exactly the set of vertices that have no in-edges from vertices in S.

For a given partial solution L consisting of some number of vertices that are already in the order, the set S of remaining vertices, and the set X of vertices in S that have no in-edges from other vertices in S, the call Generate(L, X, S) will generate all valid topological orders beginning with L.

### Generate(L, X, S):

- If X is empty:

  - Either L is already a complete solution, in which case it contains all n vertices and S is also empty, or the original graph contains a cycle.
  - If S is empty:

    - Output L as a solution.
  - Otherwise:

    - Report that a cycle exists.  (In fact, *all* vertices in S participate in some cycle, though there may be more than one.)
- Otherwise:

  - For each x in X:

    - Let L' be L with x added to the end.
    - Let X' be X\{x} plus any vertices whose only in-edge among vertices in S came from x.
    - Let S' = S\{x}.
    - Generate(L', X', S')

To kick things off, find the set X of all vertices having no in-edges and call Generate((), X, V).  Because every x chosen in the "For each" loop is different, every partial solution L' generated by the iterations of this loop must also be distinct, so no solution is generated more than once by any call to Generate(), including the top-level call.

In practice, forming X' can be done more efficiently than the above pseudocode suggests: When we choose x, we can delete all out-edges from x, but also add them to a temporary list of edges, and by tracking the total number of in-edges for each vertex (e.g. in an array indexed by vertex number) we can efficiently detect which vertices now have 0 in-edges and should thus be added to X'.  Then at the end of the loop iteration, all the edges that we deleted can be restored from the temporary list.

Comment: I was at a meetup and spoke to a Google software developer. They agreed that a brute force recursion is the only way to get all possible results.

Answer (score 3):

An algorithm for generating all topological sorts for a given DAG (aka generating all linear extensions of a partial order) is given in the paper ["Generating Linear Extensions Fast" by Pruesse and Ruskey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.52.3057&rank=1). The algorithm has an amortized running time that is linear in the *output* (e.g.: if it outputs M topological sorts, it runs in time O(M)).

Note that in general you can't really have anything that has a runtime that's efficient with respect to the size of the input since the size of the output can be exponentially larger than the input. For example, a completely disconnected DAG of N nodes has N! possible topological sorts.

Answer (score 1):

**So this approach is flawed!** Unsure if it can be salvaged, I'll leave it a little while, if anyone can spot how to fix it, either grab what you can and post a new answer or edit mine.

Specifically, I used the below algorithm on the example from the comment and it will not output the example given, so it is clearly flawed.

---

The way I've learned to do a topological sort is the following:

- Create a list of all the elements with no arrows pointing into it
- Create a dictionary of element -> number, where element here is any element in the original collection that has an arrow into it, and the number is how many elements point to it.
- Create a dictionary of element -> list, where element here is any element in the original collection that has an arrow out of it, and the list is all the elements those arrows point to

In your example, the two dictionaries and the list would be like this:

```
D1      D2         List
W: 1    V: W, X    V
Y: 1    W: Y, Z
Z: 2    X: Z
X: 1
```

Then, start a loop where on each iteration you do the following:

- Output all elements of the list, these currently have no arrows pointing into them. Make a temporary copy of the list, and clear the list, preparing it for the following iteration
- Loop through the temporary copy, and find each element (if it exists) in the dictionary that is element -> list
- For each element in those lists, decrement the corresponding number in the element -> number dictionary by 1 (removing 1 arrow). Once a number for an element here reaches 0, add that element to the list (it has no arrows left)
- If the list is non-empty, redo the iteration loop

If you reach this point, and the dictionary with element -> number still has any elements left in it with a number above 0 (if you want to, you can remove the elements as you go in the above iteration once their numbers reach zero to make this part easier), then you have a cycle, since the above loop should not terminate until all arrows have been removed.

For your example, each iteration would output the following:

1. V
2. W, X (2nd iteration output both W and X)
3. Y, Z

If you want to know how I arrived at this solution, simply go through my iteration description step by step using the above dictionaries and list as the starting point.

---

Now, to specifically answer your question, how to output all combinations. The only places where "combinations" comes into play is per iteration. Basically, all the elements that you output in the first step of the iteration (the ones you made a temporary copy of) are considered "equivalent" and any internal ordering between these would have no impact on the topological sort.

So, do this:

- In the first point in the iteration, place those elements into a list, and add that to another list, giving you a list of lists
- This lists of lists will now contain each iteration as one element, and one element will be yet another list with the elements output in that iteration
- Now, combine all permutations of the first list with all the permutations of the second list with all the permutations of the third list, and so on

This means taking this output:

1. V
2. W, X
3. Y, Z

Which gives you 1 * 2 * 2 = 4 permutations in total and you would combine all permutations of the 1st iteration (which is 1) with all the permutations of the 2nd iteration (which is 2, W, X and X, W) with all the permutations of the 3rd iteration (which is 2, Y, Z and Z, Y).

The final list of permutations that are valid topological sorts would be this:

1. V, W, X, Y, Z
2. V, X, W, Y, Z
3. V, W, X, Z, Y
4. V, X, W, Z, Y

---

Here is the example from the comment:

> A and B with no in-edges. Both A and B have an edge to C, but only A has an edge to D. Neither C nor D has any out-edges.

Which gives:

```
A --> C
A --> D
B --> C
```

Dictionaries and list:

```
D1     D2        List
C: 2   A: C, D   A
D: 1   B: C      B
```

Iterations would output:

1. A, B
2. D, C

All permutations (2 * 2 = 4):

1. A, B, D, C
2. A, B, C, D
3. B, A, D, C
4. B, A, C, D

Comment: I can't put my finger on it but it seems I've missed a step or forgotten something, please read the above critically and see if it is flawed, and hopefully if it can be corrected.

Comment: OK, so the output `A, D, B, C` was not possible with my algorithm. I guess my algorithm is doable for finding *a* topological sort output, not *all* of them.

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen Thanks for the effort and looks 90% right! I knew there probably wasn't a simple solution to this.